# Prove that $f\in L^{1} (\mathbb{R})\setminus L^{2}(\mathbb{R}) $ from function

Tags: functions

The functions $f, g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}$ is defined by the following:

$f(t) :=
 \begin{cases}%
  t^{-1/2}       & \text{if $t\in (0, 1],$}\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
$

$g(t) :=
 \begin{cases}%
  t^{-1}       & \text{if $t\in [1, +\infty ),$}\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
$

Is it possible to prove that $f\in L^{1} (\mathbb{R})\setminus L^{2}(\mathbb{R})
$ or $g\in L^{2} (\mathbb{R})\setminus L^{1}(\mathbb{R})
$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried calculating the integrals?

Comment: @supinf yes but in vain. I am no good at math, maybe that's the bottleneck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use

$\int_0 \frac{dx}{x^a}$ converges$ \iff a<1$

and

$\int^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^b}$ converges$\iff b>1$

we can say

$f$ is $L^1(\mathbb R) (a=\frac 12)$ but not $L^2 \;(a=1)$

and $g$ is $L^2 \;(b=2)$ but not $L^1\;(b=1)$.

Comment: So is there a function $h$ such that: $ h\in L^{2} (\mathbb{R}) \\and \\ L^{1}(\mathbb{R}) ? $

Comment: $t:\mapsto e^{-t}$